# Verifying data sent by ajax

Tags: php, jquery

On my site i have login area, where logged-in users can change text stored in database. Every user has one (or 2 or 3) texts, with specific id for each one. Here is how database for messages looks:

```
  | message_id | message_text | user_id | time |
```

Message_id and userid are three or four-digit numbers.

Until now, i was using clean PHP to save/get data from base. But now i want to use AJAX, and here is how my call looks (when user finish editing his message and hits submit):

```
var msg = $("#msg").val();
var usrid = $("usrid").val();
var msgid = $("#msgid").val();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    action: 'save_message',
    message: msg,
    user_id: usrid,
    message_id: msgid
},
url: 'http://example.com/update.php',
success: function(data) {
        $('#info').html('<b>Message saved!!!</b>');
        }
})
```

But, as we all know, JQuery (JS) is client-side language, and user can easily change values of usrid, msgid, and after few tries he will change message of some other user.

What is right solution for this? To pass some kind of token, to make id's more complicated (10, 20-digit numbers) or some other solution?

Comment: Check out this: http://advosys.ca/papers/web/60-form-tampering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already had a clean PHP solution for all the POST data handling you can just reuse the same validation methods because AJAX submits the data to you as a POST.
Unless if you didn't have any validation server side and you submited the user id's together with the form data then I would recommend using PHP sessions as @Briguy37 recommended.
If you want a good example to validate/clean post data CodeIgniter has a really good security library part of it's core that is quite easy to implement.

Comment: Well, in my PHP version, for userid i use userid from php session.

Answer (score 0):

Look into PHP sessions.  When a user first logs in, associate their user id with the session.  Then, when they post a message, use the user id from the session rather than passing it from the client.  If your login process is secure, this should avoid users updating messages of other users.

Comment: I aready use PHP sessions in my existing PHP solution. But how to send id from session with AJAX, so that id cant be changed?

Comment: @SomeoneS:  You cannot, because a client can construct and send whatever AJAX request they want.  Thus, if you provide a way to send a userId and don't check that userId on the server, users will be able to post for other users if they have the right ids.  It might work if you keep ids secret or generate a secret key/guid for each user that they use for posting.  However, if other users get the secret userId/key/guid, they will be able to post on behalf of that user.  In my opinion, this just adds complexity and doesn't improve security, so I highly recommend going with session validation.

Comment: you say that i should stick with PHP?

Comment: @SomeoneS:  Send the AJAX request as in your original question without the userId.  Handle the AJAX request with a PHP page on your server that saves the provided message with the userId from the session.